# Cookies not persisting with external sites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, asp.net-core, google-chrome-extension

Asp.net core session is always null when I call my server through GitHub.com from my google extension.

If I do the exact same through my own localhost:8080 website then it works fine but it seems that requests from external domains don't persist the cookie for the session.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddSession(options => new SessionOptions
{
    Cookie = new CookieBuilder
    {
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
        IsEssential = true,
        Name = ".onboardor",
    }
});

app.UseSession(new SessionOptions
{
    Cookie = new CookieBuilder
    {
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
        IsEssential = true,
        Name = ".onboardor",
    }
});
```

No idea why their are two ways to pass sessionoptions...

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var value = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Test");

    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test", "randomValue");

    return null;
}
```

js:

```
fetch("https://localhost:8080/test", {
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  method: "get",
});
```

[image]

You can see in the image above that the cookie is actually there but it seems to get removed immediately when refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Session wasn't working properly because for CORS you need to set samesite mode for cookies to none.

```
        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
        });

        app.UseSession(new SessionOptions {
            Cookie = new CookieBuilder
            {
                Name = ".AspNetCore.Session",
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
            }
        });
```